# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\wamp\www\loginoops\user1.php on in line 9

Tags: php

I have php class in my project for login and registration, 
how to include that class in my registration.php file and create object,
when i include by include function than this error is occured
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\wamp\www\loginoops\user1.php on line 9,
Please help me.
Code id below-

```
<?php 
include_once("connection.php");
class User1{
public $username=null;
public $password=null;
public $mobile=null;
public $email=null;
public function _construct($data=array()){
if(isset($data['name'])){this->$username=stripcslashes(strip_tags($data['name']));
}
if(isset($data['pass'])){this->$password=stripcslashes(strip_tags($data['pass']));}
if(isset($data['mobile'])){this->$mobile=stripcslashes(strip_tags($data['mobile']));}
if(isset($data['email'])){this->$password=stripcslashes(strip_tags($data['email']));}

}
public function storeFormValue($param){
this->_construct($param);
}
public function regUser($con){
$success=null;
try{
$sql="insert into user        values('".$username."','".$password."','".$mobile."','".$email."')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)
{
return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='Register.php'>Login Now</a>";

}


}
catch(Exception $e)
{
return  $e->getMessage();
}

}

}
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unexpected+T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Comment: Would you mind posting the code from `user1.php`? Mind-reading features are still in beta.

Comment: D-o-e-s-N-o-t-C-o-m-p-u-t-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$this` instead of `this` and `$this->username` instead of `this->$username`.

Comment: this error occurred                                                     Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\wamp\www\loginoops\user1.php on line 9

Comment: @Ravi  Remove the dollar sign before property name, it should be like `$this->username`.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, array given in C:\wamp\www\loginoops\user1.php on line 23

Comment: if i use mysqli_query($con,$sql) then Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, array given in C:\wamp\www\loginoops\user1.php on line 23  is come, if use mysql_query then warning is not come but in both cash data is not inserted to database.

Comment: Do you use mysql or mysqli?

Comment: I used both type,if i use mysqli then  Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, array given in C:\wamp\www\loginoops\user1.php on line 23 is come,if use mysql there is no any error or warning but data is not stored in table.

Comment: No, I meant do you use mysql to connect to database or mysqli?

Comment: i create two example one with mysql_connect and another is mysqli_connect

Comment: it says you're passing an array instead of mysqli class. perhaps you overwrite the variable somewhere or you pass the wrong variable!